# Looking for a multi user calendar

Tags: calendar

We have a team of real estate sales reps. We would like an admin to assign accounts to each sales rep, allow the rep to create appointments, and have the calendar viewable to anyone.

Ideally we would like to embed the calendar on our web site (Wordpress). If there is nothing free, we would be willing to spring for a proprietary package.

I already found this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/event-calendar-scheduler/ which looks to be exactly what we need, unfortunately it doesn't work on our site. Events can be scheduled but do not show up, and there are blank and the daily view shows up blank.

Answer (score 1):

You might find this plug-in useful: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/event-organiser/

*Full disclosure: I authored this plug-in*

You can assign permissions (to create, edit, publish events etc) to roles in the plug-in the settings. It has an admin-side calendar, and calendars for the front end. So it seems to do everything you ask for.